# can backend run more than 15min taskqueue?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

i tested run while loop trigger from frontend-taskqeue

1. to backend. after 15mins, i get  Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.
2. to backend and spawn a thread, _ah/background   Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.

Can backend run taskqeue more than 15min?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can run for hours as their documentations says, but this famous error "backend took too long to shutdown" used to appear for tasks takes up to 2 hours sometimes and some other times it may reach 4 hours before stopping the backend.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/#Java_Properties_of_backends

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Admin console and see if you have exceeded your quota for backend tasks.  You can control the number of instances and the class using backends.xml.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends